# I accidentally authenticated wrong SSH key in my ubuntu terminal. How can I fix this?

Tags: command-line, ssh, git

I am new to Git. I created a new SSH key in my terminal, added it in Github and then I tried testing SSH connection in my terminal using these commands:

> https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection

Problem is, the key fingerprint my terminal showed on using `$ ssh -T git@github.com` command is different from the original fingerprint I generated. At this point I should have entered NO in the terminal but in hurry I typed YES and only noticed the mismatch in key fingerprint later. What can I do now to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this command:

```
ssh-keygen -R github.com
```

This will remove the hostkey of github.com from the known-hosts file.

Next time you connect to github.com it will show you the hostkey-fingerprint again and ask you for confirmation.

But I am sure this is not really what you want or you think you want.

The hostkey is not related to the personal ssh-key in any way.